# TypeError: localizify.add is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am using an npm localizify in node.js and 
I am facing this error.
Code for desire problem.

```
const localizify = require('localizify');
const en = require('./languages/en.js');
const fr = require('./languages/fr.js');


localizify.add('en', en);
localizify.add('ar', ar);
app.use((req,res, next) => {
    const lang = localizify.detectLocale(req.headers['accept-language']) || 'en' ;
    localizify.setLocale(lang);
    next();
});
```

Here is an error.
[image: Error in licalizify npm in node.js]

Comment: Did you run `npm install localizify --save`?

Comment: Yes, I have installed npm localizify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you should require it:

```
const {default: localizify} = require('localizify');
```

or

```
let localizify = require('localizify');
localizify = new localizify.Instance();
```